# How may I develop two features simultaneously with Git branching?

Tags: git, git-branch

Suppose I wish to work on two features A and B. I created two corresponding branches feature-A and feature-B (in addition to the master development branch). Whenever I make changes in a branch, do I need to commit my changes before checking out to another? If so, is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Look into using `git stash`.

Comment: Indeed, `git stash` is a simple solution. You can do `git stash save "featureA"` while in featureA branch, then `git checkout featureB`, work on something else, save that via `git stash save "featureB"`. `git stash list` will show you all stashes. You can apply any staches using `git stash pop` (this will import the stash and remove the record) or `git stash apply` (the stash will still be present until you delete it)

Answer (score 1):

You could look into git [worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree). This lets you check out multiple branches at the same time in different directories. Let's say you start with two different branches:

```
git branch featureA
git branch featureB
```

You can check these out in their own directories like this:

```
git worktree add work-on-featureA featureA
git worktree add work-on-featureB featureB
```

Now you can simply move between the two feature branches by changing directories. Once you no longer need the worktree, remove it with `git worktree remove`:

```
git worktree remove work-on-featureA
git worktree remove work-on-featureB
```

Comment: this works great. And how do you deal when you feel finished with the featureA and featureB. Do you simple merge featureB with featureA or how exactly?

Comment: How you merge these branches into your default branch (or into each other) is unrelated to whether you're using worktrees or not: it really depends on your local policy. For the sort of work I do, I would probably end up merging one branch into the primary branch (e.g., `main`), and then rebase the remaining feature on `main` before continuing development (and ultimately merging the second branch into `main` when finished).